# How do I capture a button event type in swift

Tags: swift, events, ibaction

I'm having trouble finding information on how to capture touch events. Event.type and event.description does not help me, and the documentation does not have examples as far as I can tell.

I'm creating an IBAction on several buttons and want the (shared) action to deal with named buttons (sender.currentTitle) and (events.??) to add code for whether the button was tapped or long pressed.

```
 @IBAction func ChangeSort(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent!)     {
            //  Trying to capture the button action? Type?? Description?


 switch event.type   {
           case "Touch Up Inside":  
            //  Switching on currenttitle works fine.
            switch sender.currentTitle! {
            case "Amount":
                MyQueries.QppQueryOrderBy = "Order by Amount"
                //  Mylabel.text = "sss"
            default: ...
            }
        case "Touch Down Repeat":
            print("In long press")
            switch sender.currentTitle! {
            case "Amount":
                MyQueries.QppQueryOrderBy = "Order by Amount desc"
            default: ...
            }
        default:
            print("in def")
            switch sender.currentTitle! {
            case "Amount":...
                MyQueries.QppQueryOrderBy = "Order by LastActivityDate desc"
            default:
                MyQueries.QppQueryOrderBy = "Order by Amount desc"
            }

        }
        self.theTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UIEvent` you are getting back is not going to tell you what you want. UIEvent will only tell you Touches, Motion, or Remote Control. You are looking for `UIControlEvent` which is pretty hard to get ahold of from within the iBAction. The more standard way to solve this problem would be to make multiple `@IBAction func` and assign the different types of control events to the different ones.

So for all of your named buttons, you would assign the touch up inside event to the same `sortByTitle` func.

```
 @IBAction func sortByTitle(sender: UIButton)    {
        //  This is associated with TouchUpInside in IB
        switch sender.currentTitle! {
        case "Amount":
            MyQueries.QppQueryOrderBy = "Order by Amount"
            //  Mylabel.text = "sss"
        default: ...
        }
    self.theTableView.reloadData()

    }

    @IBAction func sortByTitleDescending(sender: UIButton)    {
        //This is associated with Touch Down Repeat
        print("In long press")
        switch sender.currentTitle! {
        case "Amount":
            MyQueries.QppQueryOrderBy = "Order by Amount desc"
        default: ...
        }
              self.theTableView.reloadData()
      }
```

Basically if you were to create your button in code, when you initialized it, you would add a func for each of the control events you wanted to watch for using the `addTarget` method on UIControl/UIButton. In `addTarget` you specify a different func for each one. In IB you are just doing this in graphical form.